# Ansible - Create JSON output by merging facts

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I am trying to create a JSON output from an Ansible playbook that will be sent to a 3rd party system via file or RabbitMQ.  The issue I am having is creating the JSON file/body to send as output.

**Environment**:

- Ansible: 2.10.17
- JSON input file: 'Cannot change the format of the input file'

**Logical process**:

- Receive a JSON input file => working
- Convert JSON input file to a fact (JSON_input) => working
- Search through the a directory and find any folder (bucket) not already
  listed (var_client_buckets_diff_state_current)=> working
- Create new fact which consist of [input file + var_client_buckets_diff_state_current] (create json file structure for new fact) => not
  working
- Send the new fact to 3rd party => not attempted yet

**What has been attempted**:

- Tried to use the 'update_fact' with indicies => this seemed not to
  work and was intended for updating an existing variable within the
  fact
- Tried to use the 'set_fact' + [item] => not what I expected

**Input_file**:

```json
  {
    "siteIdentifier": "site1",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "tenantName": "patcorp",
        "keypairConfigurations": [
          {
            "accessKey": "key1",
            "secretKey": "kjjhgghfdgf765ghdf",
            "port": "60008",
            "mountPath": "/tmp/mnt/scoutfs/patcorp",
            "buckets": [
              {
                "bucketName": "bucket1",
                "settings": {
                  "status": "OK"
                }
              },
              {
                "bucketName": "bucket2",
                "settings": {
                  "status": "PENDING-DELETION"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "tenantName": "mattcorp",
        "keypairConfigurations": [
          {
            "accessKey": "key3",
            "secretKey": "jhgf785tkjjhg",
            "port": "60010",
            "mountPath": "/tmp/mnt/scoutfs/mattcorp",
            "buckets": [
              {
                "bucketName": "bucket10",
                "settings": {
                  "status": "OK"
                }
              },
              {
                "bucketName": "bucket11",
                "settings": {
                  "status": "PENDING-DELETION"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

**Playbook:**

```yaml
---
- name: debug_playbook
  hosts:
    - localhost
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    var_client_buckets_diff_state_current: ['/tmp/mnt/scoutfs/mattcorp/bucket12', '/tmp/mnt/scoutfs/mattcorp/bucket22', '/tmp/mnt/scoutfs/patcorp/bucket07']
    fact_json_updated: []
  tasks:
      ## Find collections path via ansible.cfg
    - name: debug_read_collections_path
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('config', 'COLLECTIONS_PATHS') }}"
      run_once: true
      register: reg_debug_read_collections_path
    
      ## Read JSON file to create stdout
    - name: cat_scoutam_client_master_assignments_raw
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: cat ./files/scoutam_client_master_assignments_2.json
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: reg_scoutam_client_master_assignments_raw

      ## Convert JSON input file into fact
    - name: fact_scoutam_client_master_assignments
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        fact_scoutam_client_master_assignments: "{{ reg_scoutam_client_master_assignments_raw.stdout | from_json }}"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
    
#    - name: debug_scoutam_client_tenant_ids
#      debug:
#        msg: "{{ fact_scoutam_client_master_assignments | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
#      vars:
#        jmesquery: 'configurations[*].tenantName'
#      run_once: true
#      delegate_to: localhost
#      register: reg_debug_scoutam_client_tenant_ids
    
      ## Create duplicate fact file with only diffs found from 'var_client_buckets_diff_state_current'
    - name: create json file structure for new fact
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        fact_json_new:
          siteIdentifier:
          configurations:
            - {tenantName: "{{ var_tenantName }}", keypairConfigurations: [{accessKey: , secretKey: , port: , mountPath: , buckets: [{bucketName: "{{ var_bucketName }}", settings: {status: }}] }]}
      vars:
        var_tenantName: "{{ item.split('/')[4] }}" ## take 'item' and find tenant name
        var_bucketName: "{{ item.split('/')[5] }}" ## take 'item' and find bucket name
      loop: "{{ var_client_buckets_diff_state_current }}" ## loop through buckets not within input file
      register: reg_fact_json_new
      
      ## Create new JSON file (input file + any new buckets found )
    - name: combine fact
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        fact_json_updated: "{{ fact_json_updated + item }}"
      loop: "{{ reg_fact_json_new.results | json_query('[*].ansible_facts.fact_json_new')  }}"
    
    
    - name: debug fact - fact_json_updated
      debug:
        var: fact_json_updated





    
    ## End of playbook message
    - name: "debug_playbook_{{ ansible_play_name }}_completion"
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "Playbook {{ playbook_dir }}/{{ ansible_play_name }} has finished."

...
```

**Output from [create json file structure for new fact, combine fact]**

```json
TASK [combine fact] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /app/ansible/ansible_linux_playbooks/playbooks/TEST_debug_facts_playbook/debug_playbook.yml:70
Thursday 28 October 2021  10:06:50 -0400 (0:00:00.078)       0:00:01.417 ****** 
ok: [localhost] => (item={'siteIdentifier': None, 'configurations': [{'tenantName': 'mattcorp', 'keypairConfigurations': [{'accessKey': None, 'secretKey': None, 'port': None, 'mountPath': None, 'buckets': [{'bucketName': 'bucket12', 'settings': {'status': None}}]}]}]}) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "fact_json_updated": [
            {
                "configurations": [
                    {
                        "keypairConfigurations": [
                            {
                                "accessKey": null,
                                "buckets": [
                                    {
                                        "bucketName": "bucket12",
                                        "settings": {
                                            "status": null
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "mountPath": null,
                                "port": null,
                                "secretKey": null
                            }
                        ],
                        "tenantName": "mattcorp"
                    }
                ],
                "siteIdentifier": null
            }
        ]
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "configurations": [
            {
                "keypairConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "accessKey": null,
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "bucketName": "bucket12",
                                "settings": {
                                    "status": null
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "mountPath": null,
                        "port": null,
                        "secretKey": null
                    }
                ],
                "tenantName": "mattcorp"
            }
        ],
        "siteIdentifier": null
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'siteIdentifier': None, 'configurations': [{'tenantName': 'mattcorp', 'keypairConfigurations': [{'accessKey': None, 'secretKey': None, 'port': None, 'mountPath': None, 'buckets': [{'bucketName': 'bucket22', 'settings': {'status': None}}]}]}]}) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "fact_json_updated": [
            {
                "configurations": [
                    {
                        "keypairConfigurations": [
                            {
                                "accessKey": null,
                                "buckets": [
                                    {
                                        "bucketName": "bucket12",
                                        "settings": {
                                            "status": null
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "mountPath": null,
                                "port": null,
                                "secretKey": null
                            }
                        ],
                        "tenantName": "mattcorp"
                    }
                ],
                "siteIdentifier": null
            },
            {
                "configurations": [
                    {
                        "keypairConfigurations": [
                            {
                                "accessKey": null,
                                "buckets": [
                                    {
                                        "bucketName": "bucket22",
                                        "settings": {
                                            "status": null
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "mountPath": null,
                                "port": null,
                                "secretKey": null
                            }
                        ],
                        "tenantName": "mattcorp"
                    }
                ],
                "siteIdentifier": null
            }
        ]
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "configurations": [
            {
                "keypairConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "accessKey": null,
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "bucketName": "bucket22",
                                "settings": {
                                    "status": null
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "mountPath": null,
                        "port": null,
                        "secretKey": null
                    }
                ],
                "tenantName": "mattcorp"
            }
        ],
        "siteIdentifier": null
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'siteIdentifier': None, 'configurations': [{'tenantName': 'patcorp', 'keypairConfigurations': [{'accessKey': None, 'secretKey': None, 'port': None, 'mountPath': None, 'buckets': [{'bucketName': 'bucket07', 'settings': {'status': None}}]}]}]}) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "fact_json_updated": [
            {
                "configurations": [
                    {
                        "keypairConfigurations": [
                            {
                                "accessKey": null,
                                "buckets": [
                                    {
                                        "bucketName": "bucket12",
                                        "settings": {
                                            "status": null
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "mountPath": null,
                                "port": null,
                                "secretKey": null
                            }
                        ],
                        "tenantName": "mattcorp"
                    }
                ],
                "siteIdentifier": null
            },
            {
                "configurations": [
                    {
                        "keypairConfigurations": [
                            {
                                "accessKey": null,
                                "buckets": [
                                    {
                                        "bucketName": "bucket22",
                                        "settings": {
                                            "status": null
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "mountPath": null,
                                "port": null,
                                "secretKey": null
                            }
                        ],
                        "tenantName": "mattcorp"
                    }
                ],
                "siteIdentifier": null
            },
            {
                "configurations": [
                    {
                        "keypairConfigurations": [
                            {
                                "accessKey": null,
                                "buckets": [
                                    {
                                        "bucketName": "bucket07",
                                        "settings": {
                                            "status": null
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "mountPath": null,
                                "port": null,
                                "secretKey": null
                            }
                        ],
                        "tenantName": "patcorp"
                    }
                ],
                "siteIdentifier": null
            }
        ]
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "configurations": [
            {
                "keypairConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "accessKey": null,
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "bucketName": "bucket07",
                                "settings": {
                                    "status": null
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "mountPath": null,
                        "port": null,
                        "secretKey": null
                    }
                ],
                "tenantName": "patcorp"
            }
        ],
        "siteIdentifier": null
    }
}

TASK [debug fact - reg_fact_json_updated] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /app/ansible/ansible_linux_playbooks/playbooks/TEST_debug_facts_playbook/debug_playbook.yml:77
Thursday 28 October 2021  10:06:50 -0400 (0:00:00.100)       0:00:01.518 ****** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "fact_json_updated": [
        {
            "configurations": [
                {
                    "keypairConfigurations": [
                        {
                            "accessKey": null,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "bucketName": "bucket12",
                                    "settings": {
                                        "status": null
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "mountPath": null,
                            "port": null,
                            "secretKey": null
                        }
                    ],
                    "tenantName": "mattcorp"
                }
            ],
            "siteIdentifier": null
        },
        {
            "configurations": [
                {
                    "keypairConfigurations": [
                        {
                            "accessKey": null,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "bucketName": "bucket22",
                                    "settings": {
                                        "status": null
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "mountPath": null,
                            "port": null,
                            "secretKey": null
                        }
                    ],
                    "tenantName": "mattcorp"
                }
            ],
            "siteIdentifier": null
        },
        {
            "configurations": [
                {
                    "keypairConfigurations": [
                        {
                            "accessKey": null,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "bucketName": "bucket07",
                                    "settings": {
                                        "status": null
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "mountPath": null,
                            "port": null,
                            "secretKey": null
                        }
                    ],
                    "tenantName": "patcorp"
                }
            ],
            "siteIdentifier": null
        }
    ]
}
```

**Expected output JSON:**

```json
{
    "siteIdentifier": "mas1-sos07",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "tenantName": "patcorp",
        "keypairConfigurations": [
          {
            "accessKey": "key1",
            "secretKey": "kjjhgghfdgf765ghdf",
            "port": "60008",
            "mountPath": "/tmp/mnt/scoutfs/patcorp",
            "buckets": [
              {
                "bucketName": "bucket1",
                "settings": {
                  "status": "OK"
                }
              },
              {
                "bucketName": "bucket2",
                "settings": {
                  "status": "PENDING-DELETION"
                }
              },
              {
                "bucketName": "bucket07",
                "settings": {
                  "status": null
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "tenantName": "mattcorp",
        "keypairConfigurations": [
          {
            "accessKey": "key3",
            "secretKey": "jhgf785tkjjhg",
            "port": "60010",
            "mountPath": "/tmp/mnt/scoutfs/mattcorp",
            "buckets": [
              {
                "bucketName": "bucket10",
                "settings": {
                  "status": "OK"
                }
              },
              {
                "bucketName": "bucket11",
                "settings": {
                  "status": "PENDING-DELETION"
                }
              },
              {
                "bucketName": "bucket12",
                "settings": {
                  "status": null
                }
              },
              {
                "bucketName": "bucket22",
                "settings": {
                  "status": null
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: you dont show the ouput you want to merge with the input file...difficult to have the result wanted

Comment: Update original post with output